# How to show image when user click on collection view

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin.forms

I have a Collection view with a label and an image. I want to make the elements to have a checkmark when clicked (instead of the default behavior, which is to change the background color).

With the code below, when the user clicks on a line, the background color is changed to gray. However, the image with a checkmark is not showed, even though I have defined a setter for the image.

````xml
    <ContentPage.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <Style TargetType="Grid">
                    <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
                        <VisualStateGroupList>
                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                                    <VisualState.Setters>
                                        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGray" />
                                        <Setter x:DataType="Image" Property="Image.Source" Value="icon_check.png" />
                                    </VisualState.Setters>
                                </VisualState>
                            </VisualStateGroup>
                        </VisualStateGroupList>
                    </Setter>
                </Style>            
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </ContentPage.Resources>


    //

    <CollectionView 
                                    x:Name="collectionview_cadastronotificacao_tipoocorrencia"
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding TipoOcorrencia}" 

                                    SelectionMode="Multiple" 
                                    BackgroundColor="White" 
                                    HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                    VerticalOptions="Center"
                                    SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged" >

                        <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Grid Padding="10" >

                                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />                                    
                                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />                                    
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                    <Image 
                                       Grid.RowSpan="1"
                                       Grid.Column="2" />

                                    <Label Grid.Column="0"
                                           Text="{Binding Descricao}"
                                           FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>

                                </Grid>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    </CollectionView>
    ```

If I change `<Setter x:DataType="Image" Property="Image.Source"` to `<Setter x:DataType="Image" Property="Source"`, an `InvalidCastException` is thrown.
````

Comment: i run with your xaml code,but it throw error,and general the visual state group named "CommonStates" with three visual states:"Normal","Disabled","Focused",have your defined your own visual states? if could,you could share your test project

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT What error does it throw? And no, I haven't defined any custom visual state. I'm only using Visual with Material. I can't share this project I'm working on. I'll see if I can build a repro to share.

Comment: @LeoZhu-MSFT I have added some details.

Comment: Try changing IsVisible property instead of Source property on Image.
Of course, in this case Source should be set before to "icon_check.png".

Comment: I just tried that and it didin't work either.

Comment: i think <Setter x:DataType="Image" Property="Image.Source" Value="icon_check.png" /> this is not the property of grid,so it will not work,you could make a customview which include the grid laber and image,then set the style like above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can refer to the answer provided by my colleague :

create a **CustomView** :

```
public partial class CustomView : ContentView
 {
   public CustomView()
    {
    InitializeComponent();
    }

public string CustomImageSource
{
    set => SetValue(CustomImageSourceProperty, value);
    get => (string)GetValue(CustomImageSourceProperty);
}
public readonly static BindableProperty CustomImageSourceProperty = BindableProperty.Create(nameof(CustomImageSource), 
                                                                                        typeof(string), 
                                                                                        typeof(CustomView), 
                                                                                        defaultValue: string.Empty,
                                                                                        propertyChanged: (bindableObject, oldValue, newValue) =>
                                                                                        {
                                                                                            ((CustomView)bindableObject).MyImage.Source = ImageSource.FromFile((string)newValue);
                                                                                        });
}
```

int **CustonView.xaml**:

```
<ContentView.Content>
  <Grid Padding="10" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Image x:Name="MyImage" Grid.RowSpan="1" Grid.Column="2" />
    <Label Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding Descricao}" FontAttributes="Bold" FontSize="Small"/>
  </Grid>
</ContentView.Content>
```

finally change your page.xaml:

```
<ContentPage.Resources>
 <ResourceDictionary>
    <Style TargetType="local:CustomView">
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                    <VisualState x:Name="Selected">
                        <VisualState.Setters>
                            <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="LightGray" />
                            <Setter Property="CustomImageSource" Value="leftcircle.png" />
                        </VisualState.Setters>
                    </VisualState>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
</ContentPage.Resources>
<StackLayout>
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionview_cadastronotificacao_tipoocorrencia" 
                ItemsSource="{Binding TipoOcorrencia}"  
                SelectionMode="Multiple"  
                BackgroundColor="White"  
                HorizontalOptions="Center"  
                VerticalOptions="Center" 
                SelectionChanged="CollectionView_SelectionChanged" >

    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:CustomView/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
</StackLayout>
```

and another way is like zpouip said, let `Image` binding `IsVisible` property,you should add a `bool` type property into your datamodel,when you select ,you should change the added property value ,then the Image will display